# Google calendar API asking for "manage your contacts" permission?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have created a new google account and enabled google calendar api.

When Google asks the user for permission, it asks for "Manage your calendars" and "manage your contacts".

Why am i getting "manage your contacts"? I just want my app to manage the calendar, and I didn't turn on anything other than google calendar.  Is this necessary for all google calendar apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this may be happening because Google wants to relay people found on a users calendar to see if they are a contact so that they can provide more information on that person or event(as google connects literally everything).

I suggest you look at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing) for further information, but I am assuming you will be locked in to this permission on any google calendar request.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation 4ked.  I was hoping it was something I can remove, as it may put some people off (wtf!! why do they want to know my contacts????) but I guess I can explain that to anyone who complains.